# Select kpi with month on columns

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

I want to get two plant's oee per month in a specific year (2013), probably it's pretty trivial but I don't know how to do it:

```
with member [Measures].[OEE] as 'OEE'
select
{
    [Equipment].[Plant Hierarchy].[Group].[DEMO_PLANT],
    [Equipment].[Plant Hierarchy].[Group].[DEMO_PLANT2]
} on columns,
{
    [Time].[Month]
} on rows
from ExpertPlan
where [Time].[Year].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00]
```

the select is ok (plants on columns and months on rows), but i'm not sure about the "with" usage to get the values be the [Measures].[OEE]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `with member [Measures].[OEE] as 'OEE'`? Are you trying to create a calculated member?

Answer (score 1):

`With` is for custom calculated members and custom sets.

Add your measure to the `slicer` (`WHERE` clause)

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Equipment].[Plant Hierarchy].[Group].[DEMO_PLANT]
   ,[Equipment].[Plant Hierarchy].[Group].[DEMO_PLANT2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Time].[Month]} ON ROWS
FROM ExpertPlan
WHERE 
  (
    [Time].[Year].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00]
   ,[Measures].[OEE]
  );
```

Here are a couple of prototyped ways of approaching this in AdvWrks cube:

```
SELECT 
  [Customer].[Country].&[United States] ON COLUMNS
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  (
    [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
  );


SELECT 
  [Customer].[Country].&[United States] ON COLUMNS
 ,Descendants
  (
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount];
```

Both of the above result in this result cell set:

[image]

Comment: nope, it doesn't make sense (and i got an empty recordset). The final result I'm trying to get is the oee for demo_plant and demo_plant2 for the year 2013, divided by month

Comment: which bit does not make sense?

Comment: it is standard practice to put the measure you require in the WHERE clause if you're already using dimensions, other than Measures, on the other two axes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the other answer, you can also employ a `subselect`.

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Equipment].[Plant Hierarchy].[Group].[DEMO_PLANT]
   ,[Equipment].[Plant Hierarchy].[Group].[DEMO_PLANT2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Time].[Month]} ON ROWS
FROM 
    (
    SELECT [Time].[Year].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00] ON 0 
    FROM [ExpertPlan]
    )
WHERE 
   {[Measures].[OEE]}
```

In MDX, `WHERE` is the 3rd axis, although it is not too apparent. Think it to be like excel, where you have the rows, columns and values. You can put the hierarchies(attribute) on any of the axes(`[Measures]` also behaves like any regular hierarchy). It will just change the way your final output will look like.